# Rider keeps removing a test project from solution

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

Trying in Rider 2018 (latest + nightly), and Unity 2018.

Steps I do to reproduce this:

- I create a new Unity project, add sample editor + game class.
- I open it in Rider (for some reason it doesn't want to work with 4.x framework and makes whole project full of errors, so I switch to 3.x.
- I create nUnit test project, and this time it doesn't want to run in 3.x so i switch test to 4.x
- I write sample test and it is all right, tests work for hours...
- Suddenly test project is gone from solution. I can do Add -> Add Existing project, and all works again, sometimes it is gone in a minute, sometimes it lasts longer, tests run, but it is gone no matter what I do anyway.

Why am I not creating a new test project from Unity via: Create -> Testing -> Test Assembly Folder? Well it works, but the problem is I am unable to execute tests from both Visual Studio 2017 (no tests found), or from Rider - always "inconclusive tests". And since for every tiny change to switch for Unity, just to test Unity independent test cases, it makes development unbearable. Any way to execute those tests in any IDE directly?

Answer (score 2):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/adding-c-project-to-the-unity-solution.192047/
It is removed by Unity itself.
I would recommend you to add a separate solution and add your Unity and UnitTests projects to it.
Also it is worth updating to latest Rider nightly, which has a lot of fixes in Unity support plugin. 
https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000009804-How-to-get-Rider-Nightly-build-